# controllerDidChangeContext not being called after adding a new contact

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Basically it looks like my NSFetchedResultsController isn't detecting changes, so I don't even think the new object being created here is being saved.

```
else if segue.identifier == "AddContact" {
        let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let addViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! NewContactViewController
        let contactEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        let newContact = Contact(entity: contactEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        addViewController.contact = newContact
        addViewController.context = newContact.managedObjectContext
        addViewController.delegate = self
    }
```

After the user presses done to return to the contacts list view this is called as per a delegate I created.

```
func didFinishViewController(viewController:NewContactViewController, didSave:Bool) {

    // 1
    if didSave {
        // 2
        let context = viewController.context
        context.performBlock({ () -> Void in
            if context.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    print("Error: \(nserror.localizedDescription)")
                    abort()
                }
            }

            // 3
            self.coreDataStack.saveContext()
        })
    }
```

After checking the context's millions of time they're always matching, so the pushing is working properly, but it seems as if changes are being recorded. The CoreDataStack.swift is as such.

```
//exablishes the directory to be used for the stack in SQLite fashion
private lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

//establishes the object model that interacts with the GUI object data model
private lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(self.modelName, withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

//establishes the coordinator that connects the managed context with the persistent store
private lazy var psc: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = { let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(
    managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(self.modelName + ".sqlite")

    do {
        let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : true]

        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType( NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil) //establishes the actual persistent store
    } catch {
        print("Error adding persistent store.")
    }
    return coordinator
}()


//establishes the managed context by which managed objects interact in reading and writing
lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.psc
    return managedObjectContext
}()

func saveContext () {
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            print("Error: \(nserror.localizedDescription)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

NSFetchedResultsController implementation

```
// MARK: Fetched Results controller
func contactListFetchedResultsController()-> NSFetchedResultsController {

    fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: contactListFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        abort()
    }

        return fetchedResultController
}

func contactListFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contact")
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequest
}
```

Comment: Can you post your implementation of NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods?

Comment: Up there, should be all of it.

Comment: The save from a NSManagedContext is synchronous for the context, but asynchronous to the disk. It's passed to the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator which saves it to disk in it's own thread.

Comment: So instead of passing the context from view to view I need to be sending the instance of coreDataStack and accessing it's context directly?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have `context.performBlock` when you are already on the UI thread?  Do you have more than one context you are working with?

Assuming that you are using more than one context, you are saving the main context before the child context as `performBlock()` while cause the child context to save *after* the call to `self.coreDataStack.saveContext()`.

Since this is all UI related code you are probably better off just using the main queue context for the entire UI and I suspect your `NSFetchedResultsController` will start receiving notifications.

Comment: The child context is only for editing a contact, I'm simply working right now in 1 context.

Comment: Are you setting breakpoints and making sure all of this is firing?  Generally an issue with `NSFetchedResultsController` firing is either multi-context not saving correctly or something not wired up.  Breakpoints will help to make sure everything is firing properly and you can confirm that the delegate methods are or are not firing.

Comment: Well I've been checking to make sure the context is being pushed to each view and that works. But the issues are coming up when it tries saving in the list view. It's as if the temp contact from the contactViewController is not being transferred to the contactListView

Comment: Is the save firing?  That is the next question.  Is the new entity making it to disk?  Does it show up on a restart of the app?

Comment: When looking at the read/write under the debug window, there's no changes so I think the NSFetchedResultsController is saving Contact object that are completely nil so nothings showing up. But if it was even saving an empty object there should be a change in the debug window.

Comment: The `NSFetchedResultsController` does not "save" nor does it "create" objects.  It feeds off the changes from the `NSManagedObjectContext` that it is associated with and then calls its delegate methods. That is all that it does. If you cannot follow the flow in your app then I recommend building a test app and duplicating the behavior. Then you can share the test code with us and we can help you solve the issue.  If it does not repeat in the test then that confirms there is an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you haven't implemented NSFetchedresultsControllerDelegate methods:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    case .Move, .Update:
        break
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: NSManagedObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    case .Update:
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    case .Move:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Scratch my last comment. Did this and am still not getting the contact saved in the list.

Comment: Did you view controller adopt `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol?

Comment: yes `class ContactsViewController: ToolbarTabSuper, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, ContactEntryDelegate`